# Dynamic height noScrolable UICollectionView in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add a `dynamic height` `nonScrollable` `UICollectionView` into `UICollectionViewCell`. (It is easy to add a static height UICollectionView in UICollectionViewCell as explained by Ash Furrow)

After spending hours on searching through the web I still don't get it.

**This is what I want**

[image]

Lets call:
Main CollectionView: ParentCollectionView
Inside CollectionView: ChildCollectionView

I want to get the height of ChildCollectionView so that i can set the cell size of the ParentCollectionView in side:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let text = "I'm trying to get a label in a cell.."
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrameForEventText = (text as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: view.frame.width - 30, height: 1000), options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], context: nil)
        return CGSize.init(width: view.frame.width - 10, height: 320 + estimatedFrameForEventText.height + 60)
}
```

Also want to change the height constant of the ChildCollectionView with this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: eventCellId, for: indexPath) as! EventCell
        cell.eventText.text = "I'm trying to get a label in a cell.."

        // height constraint of ChildCollectionView in ParentCell
        cell.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.collectionView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        return cell
}
```

The scrolling of ChildCollectionView is purposely disabled to show the ChildCollectionViewCells all together.

**This is where I am stuck**

[image]

I am not abel to preCalculate the ChildCollectionView to pass them in the ParentCollectionView delegates

Both the CollectionView uses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

I am new to iOS developing.
Any help would be appreciated  :)

Comment: Since the content of your collection view is not scrollable, you might want to rethink a collection view within another collection view. In the case where you really have to do something like that you can actually do a check if collectionView == ParentCollectionView inside your delegate methods to figure out which one you are currently interacting with.

Comment: In terms of calculating the size of your ChildCollectionView, you will need to elaborate more on how you calculate it before I can help you on it. But generally you should be able to set constraints that sets your content with is your ChildCollectionView in this case to be relative to the cell it is in

Comment: @BenOng the ChildCollectionView is initialised inside ParentCollectionViewCell and has its dataSource and delegate as self ..... I calculate it using collectionView.intrinsicContentSize.height

Comment: @BenOng - and data is set ... I have to pass this calculated in ParentCollectionView sizeForItemAt so that the cell has a correct height including the ChildCollectionView

Comment: In this case, you can make a custom delegate method for your ChildCollectionView to update the ParentCollectionView of it's cell size

Comment: You can read up on custom delegates on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/241/protocols/1078/delegate-pattern#t=201612080114004401446)

Comment: @BenOng -- that will not help .. i have tried this before .. the ChildCollectionView contentSize.height remains 0.0 in ParentCell init(frame: method) ... this is because the ChildCollectionView delegate and dataSource is in the ParentCell itself ... is there any method in UICollectionViewCell class that runs after all the ParentCell subViews are added including ChildCollectionView with its data so that i can get ChildCollectionView.contentSize.height ....??                                 

thanks for your replies though :)

Comment: Since the datasource of your child is the parent and not the view controller, why can you not able to calculate how many items there will be?

Comment: The datasource needs to provide the amount of items and optionally the size of each item, that is enough to calculate how much space the collection view will need to show all its items

Comment: So you just need to divide the width of the parent cell by that of the child cell to get the amount of cells in a row then divide the amount of child cells by the amount of cells in a row to get the number of row then multiply that by the height of the cell plus the padding between each cell to get the height of the parent cell.

Comment: @BenOng --- thank you brother .. this is quite a raw method but i like it ... it works... Considering that the Child cells are powered by an API i have done few changes in the algorithm... :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem

**ParentCollectionViewController**

```
var height: CGFloat!

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: eventCellId, for: indexPath) as! EventCell

    cell.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = height!
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    var sizeOfChildCell: CGRect!
    var widthOfCells: CGFloat! = 0.0
    let cellPadding = 10
    let widthOfChildCollectionview = view.frame.width - 120
    for tag in tags {
        sizeOfChildCell = ("#\(tag)" as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: widthOfChildCollectionview, height: 1000), options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], context: nil)
        widthOfCells = widthOfCells + sizeOfChildCell.width + cellPadding + 3.8
    }
    let numOfRows = ceil(widthOfCells / widthOfChildCollectionview)
    height = numOfRows  * 25
    height = height + numOfRows * 3.8
    return CGSize.init(width: view.frame.width - 10, height: 320  + height)
}
```

**ParentCollectionViewCell**

```
var childCollectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

lazy var childCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.isScrollEnabled = false
    cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
}()

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    childCollectionViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childCollectionView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 96)
    addConstraint(childCollectionViewHeightConstraint)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future searches on this subject. I'm using IGListKit with a cell that contains a UICollectionView that holds my tags. My problem was that IGListKit isn't built very well on the AutoLayout principles so to prevent the collectionview cells from overlapping each other I had to calculate the height for the section manually before it's shown.

My idea was to just add the width of each tag (+ padding + minimumInterimSpace) and determine when the next tag supersedes the collection view width.

```
func calculateDimensions() {
   //This is how IGListKit forwards the width, could be replaced with collectionView.containerSize.width
   let width = collectionContext!.containerSize.width

   var lineWidth:CGFloat = 0.0
   var lines = 0
   for tag in data.arrTags {
       //Calculate bounds by using boundingRect
       let size = TextSize.size(tag, font: Font.fontRegular(size: 13), height: 30)
       //16= 8 padding-left + 8 padding-right 
       //5 = minimumInterimSpace
       let itemWidth = 16 + size.width + 5 
       let tmpWidth = lineWidth + itemWidth
       if tmpWidth > width {
           lines += 1
           lineWidth = itemWidth
       }
       lineWidth += itemWidth
    }

    sectionHeight = CGFloat( lines * 30 + (lines * 5)) + 15 
}
```

This method is called when IGListKit sets the size for the current section. So I did this:

```
override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
    calculateDimensions()
    let size = CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: sectionHeight)
    return size
}
```

This will result in the following:
[image: Left aligned tags in embedded collectionview]